# Is it possible for nested subcomponents to receive events from parent components in Lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, event

Lets assume we have the following hierarchy of Lightning Components

```
<c:master>
    <c:sibling1 aura:id="sibling1" />
</c:master>
```

**PART I**

Is it possible for a child component (here `sibling1`) to handle an APPLICATION event registered in `master`'s markup and fired in `master`'s js-controller?

I have an issue with that, where I have the same handler in master and sibling1 declared, but only `master` is receiving (or handling) the event, **but not sibling1**.

Here is my code reduced to the basics

master.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="masterApex" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" >
    <aura:registerEvent   name="change"     type    ="c:changeEvent"/>
    <aura:handler         name="change"     event   ="c:changeEvent" action="{!c.handleChange}"/>
    <a><ui:outputText value="do it" click="{!c.fireTheChange}"/></a>
    <c:sibling1 aura:id="sibling1" />
</aura:component>
```

masterController.js

```
fireTheChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("fireTheChange");       
    var fireEvent = component.getEvent("change");
    fireEvent.fire();
},

handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("handleChange");
},
```

sibling1.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="sibling1Apex" implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable" >
    <aura:handler         name="change"     event   ="c:changeEvent" action="{!c.handleChange}"/>
</aura:component>
```

sibling1Controller.js

```
handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {
    console.log("____R_E_C_E_I_V_E_D____");
},
```

changeEvent.evt

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" >
</aura:event>
```

Now if i click on "do click" in the console.log I got only

```
fireTheChange
handleChange
```

but I'm missing

```
____R_E_C_E_I_V_E_D____
```

**PART II**

To interact with nested child components, is there only the APPLICATION event? Would a COMPONENT event work, too? Are there other ways for `master` of interacting with `sibling1` without events at all? I found that setting `sibling1`'s attributes from `master` is easy in masterController.js

```
var sibling1 = component.find('sibling1');
sibling1.set("v.whateverAttributeName","aNiceValue");
```

Now is it also possible to execute siblings controller-methods and let it rerender from within masterController.js?

Or is there an other recommend pattern for that?

Answer (score 7):

There is a lot going on in this post so I'll give you some thoughts but can't answer everything.

1.
The preferred way for parent to child communication is to use `<aura:method>`. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cmp_methods.htm
It should be a bit simpler than using events.

2.
You declare changeEvent.evt as an application event but the syntax, `component.getEvent("change")`, is used for component events. Try `$A.get("e.c:changeEvent")` instead for an application event. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application.htm

3.
It's probably ok to use `<aura:handler name="change" ..>` but try name="somethingElse" instead in case there is some side effect of name="change", which is used in automatic change handlers. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm.

Comment: These conceptual answers are exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot @MarkL, I'll check them out in the next days.